# Comparing DateTime object in Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, datetime, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to create a linq query to get all date 1 year back (expecting 365 values)

```
 using (var context = new Context1())
 {
      var query = (from c in context.Daily25Data
                   where c.Date > DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)
                   select c).ToList();

                   Console.WriteLine(query);
 }
```

tried to use the above code but get exception

> Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddYears(Int32)' method, and this method
>   cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just pull the value out into a variable before you execute your query:

```
var oneYearEarlier = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);

var query = (from c in context.Daily25Data
             where c.Date > oneYearEarlier
             select c).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Agreed with the @RB answer. You can also use [`DbFunctions.AddYears`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.addyears(v=vs.113)) static method:

```
var query = (from c in context.Daily25Data
               where c.Date > DbFunctions.AddYears(DateTime.Now,-1)
               select c).ToList();
```